# How to reverse button gradient when hovering over it

Tags: html, css

How can you reverse a gradient when hovering over a button? See the Read More buttons here to see this effect in action: https://carney.co/daily-carnage/. Notice how when you hover over the button, the yellow color moves to the left and pink moves to the right.

I tried turning off the transition on the button container to see if that's how it's done but the hover effect is still there even after disabling this.

When hovering over the button, I would like the yellow color to now be on the left and the pink to be on the right (so reversed)

Comment: Just redefine the gradient in the CSS for the `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you provided, you can use before and after suedo classes. You can remove the transition of the Before to eliminate potential "flash" of white.

example: https://codepen.io/SROwl/pen/MdjLvj

```
<button>Gradient Change</button>  



  button {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  button::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: linear-gradient(purple, orange);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease;
  }
  button::after {
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(orange, purple);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease;
  }
  button:hover::before, button:active::before, button:focus::before {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  button:hover::after, button:active::after, button:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

To reverse gradient on `hover`

**HTML**

```
   <div id="dd">This is div</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dd {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow, #ff0066);
  }

#dd:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, yellow, #ff0066); 

  /* or */
  /* background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff0066, yellow); */
  }
```